How can I have TJsonArray with 1D or 2D while converting ObjectToJson
I have a record like below,
type
  TSensorData = record
    Name: string;
    Units: string;
    Values: TJsonArray;
  end;

In my JSON, this Values can be 1D or 2D array. Since Variant didn't work, I used TJsonArray.
....
jsonArray = TJsonArray.create;
jsonArray.add(10);
jsonArray.Add(20);

TSensorData.Name = "Speed";
TSensorData.Unit = "m/s";
TSensorData.Values = jsonArray; //1D

serializer := TJsonSerializer.Create(slPublishedProperty); //Using quicklib
JsonString := serializer.ObjectToJson(TSensorData,True); 

In another case,
oJsonArray = TJsonArray.create;
iJsonArray = TJsonArray.create;
ijsonArray.add(10);
ijsonArray.Add(20);
oJsonArray.Add(iJsonArray)

TSensorData.Name = "Speed envelop";
TSensorData.Unit = "array of m/s";
TSensorData.Values = oJsonArray; //2D

serializer := TJsonSerializer.Create(slPublishedProperty); //Using quicklib
JsonString := serializer.ObjectToJson(TSensorData,True); 

When I serialize this (tried Quicklib/Neon/TJson), the Values is always empty. How can achieve dynamic array while serializing to JSON?
Note: Sometimes, my JSON contains array of TSensorData hence, I cannot use two different records unless there is a way for Delphi to support different type of records in an array.

AFAIK, one cannot serialize a TJSONArray to JSON, but I am not familiar with all listed libraries. BTW, TSensorData is declared as a type, but used like a variable in your code. That is a bit irritating.
